# Should I put an assignment in the for loop or out of it?

Tags: c, function, loops, location

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print1(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n]);
void print2(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n]);
void print3(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n]);
void print4(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n]);
void print5(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n]);
int main(void)
{
    double a[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

    print1(3, 2, &a);
    print2(3, 2, &a);
    print3(3, 2, &a);
    print4(3, 2, &a);
    print5(3, 2, &a);

    return 0;
}
void print1(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n])
{
    double subTotal;
    subTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            subTotal += (*p)[j][i];
            printf("%lf~~~", subTotal);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************\n");
}
void print2(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n])
{
    double subTotal;
    for (int i = 0, subTotal = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            subTotal += (*p)[j][i];
            printf("%lf~~~", subTotal);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************\n");
}
void print3(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n])
{
    double subTotal;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        subTotal = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            subTotal += (*p)[j][i];
            printf("%lf~~~", subTotal);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************\n");
}
void print4(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n])
{
    double subTotal;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, subTotal = 0; j < m; j++) {
            subTotal += (*p)[j][i];
            printf("%lf~~~", subTotal);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************\n");
}
void print5(int m, int n, double (*p)[m][n])
{
    double subTotal;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            subTotal = 0;
            subTotal += (*p)[j][i];
            printf("%lf~~~", subTotal);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("******************\n");
}
```

Look at the above code.   I have written five C functions which are print 1 ~ print 5.

The only difference between them is the location of **subTotal = 0**

For me, print1 , print3 and print5 are easy to understand.

I anticipate print2 is the same as print1 and print4 is the same as print3.

But the output proves me wrong. Here is the output:

```
1.000000~~~4.000000~~~9.000000~~~
11.000000~~~15.000000~~~21.000000~~~
******************
0.000000~~~0.000000~~~0.000000~~~
0.000000~~~0.000000~~~0.000000~~~
******************
1.000000~~~4.000000~~~9.000000~~~
2.000000~~~6.000000~~~12.000000~~~
******************
0.000000~~~0.000000~~~0.000000~~~
0.000000~~~0.000000~~~0.000000~~~
******************
1.000000~~~3.000000~~~5.000000~~~
2.000000~~~4.000000~~~6.000000~~~
******************
```

I can't think out why print2 and print4 prints results different from my anticipation.

Why did I understand wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here `for(int i = 0, subTotal = 0; ...` is defining *two* variables in the loop's init statement. The first is `int i`, and the second is a `int subTotal` that hides the `double subTotal` at the top of the function (leaving it unused).

As such, `print2` and `print4` are using the `%lf` format specifier to print an integer, which is undefined behavior.

Adding [`-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` to GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g3CQ9D1fhcfPoDMF) produces a warning to all of those effects.

Comment: I am not   using the %lf format specifier to print an integer.   subTotal is a double.

Comment: @SleepingOnaGiant'sShoulder - The very first paragraph explains why it's printing an integer.

Comment: I understand. THanks.

Answer (score 2):

To the question of why 0s are printed for print2 and print4:
You are using `%lf` format specifier to print an integer `subtotal` local to the `for` loop.
The C Committee draft on `printf` and `fprintf` states that:

> 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions
>   ...
>   If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.**